# Duplicate key in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, duplicates

I am trying to populate a `dictionary` with values from two files, the first file `caveConnections` populates the first key value of the dictionary. the second key value is populated `connectionWeights` the file contents are as follows

`caveConnections`

```
4
4 5
5 6 7
1 5 6
2 3 4
3 4
3
```

`connectionWeights`

```
2
8 3
2 14 5
7 6 11
2 11 6
14 1
1
```

the code that carries this out is as follows;

```
Graph g = new Graph();
for (int i = 0; i <= totalNumberOfCaves; i++)
{
    string ConnectedCaves = @"D:\UNI\Year 5\AI - SET09122\SET09122 - CW1\WriteConnectedCaves.txt";
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(ConnectedCaves);
    //adds the values to the graph
    for (int k = 0; k < lines.Length; k++)
    {
       string[] ints = lines[i].Split(' ');
       Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
       for (int j = 0; j < ints.Length; j++)
       {
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(int.Parse(ints[i].Trim())))
            {
                dict.Add(int.Parse(ints[i].Trim()), int.Parse(connectionweight.Pop()));
            }
        }
        Console.Write(dict);
        g.add_vertex(k+1, dict);
    }
}
```

as far as I can see there shouldn't be an issue but I am getting the following error when running;

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
>      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
>      at Djikstras_algo.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\UNI\Year 5\AI - SET09122\SET09122 - CW1\tests\Djikstras_algo\Djikstras_algo\Program.cs:line 186
>   Blockquote

I'm unsure as to why this error is occurring. if its useful the full project code can be found here - [Djikstras_Project](https://www.pastiebin.com/5c03b94888ef0)

Any suggestion on why this isn't working would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You're using `i` as the offset for the array `ints` where you add to the dictionary, but from the context it looks like you probably meant to use `j`.

Comment: and move `Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();` outside outermost loop

Comment: @DisplayName im takeing that you mean outside the `for (int i = 0; i <= totalNumberOfCaves; i++)`?

Comment: @steve16351 I Have just tried to use the `J` as the value instead of `I` and i get an error stating that the the input string is in the wrong format, any ideas?

Comment: @bdg, yes I meant that